# File I/O with Free Monads

Tags: scala, dsl, scalaz, scala-cats, free-monad

I have a CSV file that I need to parse and do some action on every record. How do I use Free Monads with it? Currently, I'm loading the entire file into memory and would like to know if there is any better solution. Below is my program:

```
for {
    reader <- F.getReader("my_file.csv")
    csvRecords <- C.readCSV(reader)
    _ <- I.processCSV(csvRecords)
    _ <- F.close(reader)
} yield()
```

This code works for smaller files, but if I have very large files (over 1 GB), this wouldn't work very well. I'm using [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) for reading the CSVRecords.

Comment: arjunswaj, what do you really need: a method that uses the Free Monad or any solution that works and doesn't load the whole file into the memory?

Comment: @SergGr I want a method that uses Free Monad and doesn’t load the whole file into memory.

Comment: OK, Free monad is mandatory, Could you show us your current `readCSV` and `processCSV`? [`CSVParser`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-csv.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.java;h=06108f672ac70146828e8a1e1afc0e9e76251185;hb=HEAD) seems to already provide `Iterable`/`Iterator` API

Comment: @SergGr, [here](https://gist.github.com/arjunswaj/8b22965549ac86117873d64513fbf007) is the Gist of the program that I have.

Comment: I want to do it more in an FP way - without using while loop with `hasNext`/`next` of Iterable/Iterator. Maybe by using Streams. In the current implementation above, the stream is created from the List and list has all the records in the file loaded into memory.

Comment: In what way do you think `Stream` is better than `Iterable` given the fact that `scala.collection.immutable.Stream` implements `scala.collection.Iterable` via its parents `AbstractSeq` and `AbstractIterable`? Also note that `map` is defined over `TraversableLike` which is even more base parent of `Iterable`

Comment: `Stream` provides a lazy implementation and the language/sdk handles the iteration. I wanted to avoid the `while(parser.hasNext) process(parser.next)` and stick to FP constructs like `map`/`flatmap`. I see that you have used `parser.asScala`, this should work.

Comment: Raw `Iterable` is actually as lazy as `Stream`. AFAIU the only real benefit of `Stream` is that unlike `Iterable` it might be constructed in a self-referencing way such as in a typical Fibonacci sequence example and still be lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the code at your gist I think that the line with the comment is exactly the line you don't want at all:

```
  object CSVIOInterpreter extends (CSVIO ~> Future) {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    override def apply[A](fa: CSVIO[A]): Future[A] = fa match {
      case ReadCSV(reader) => Future.fromTry(Try {
        CSVFormat.RFC4180
          .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
          .parse(reader)
          .getRecords // Loads the complete file
          .iterator().asScala.toStream
      })
    }
  }
```

Just remove the whole `getRecords` line. [`CSVFormat.parse`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#parse-java.io.Reader-) returns an instance of [CSVParser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) which already implements `Iterable<CSVRecord>`. And the `getRecords` call is the only thing that force it to read the whole file.

Actually you can see [CSVParser.getRecords](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-csv.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.java;h=06108f672ac70146828e8a1e1afc0e9e76251185;hb=HEAD#l445) implementation and it is

```
 public List<CSVRecord> getRecords() throws IOException {
     CSVRecord rec;
     final List<CSVRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
     while ((rec = this.nextRecord()) != null) {
         records.add(rec);
     }
     return records;
 }
```

So it just materializes the whole file using `this.nextRecord` call which is obviously a more "core" part of the API.

So when I do a simplified version of your code without the `getRecords` call:

```
import cats._
import cats.free.Free
import java.io._
import org.apache.commons.csv._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

trait Action[A] {
  def run(): A
}

object F {

  import Free.liftF

  case class GetReader(fileName: String) extends Action[Reader] {
    override def run(): Reader = new FileReader(fileName)
  }

  case class CloseReader(reader: Reader) extends Action[Unit] {
    override def run(): Unit = reader.close()
  }

  def getReader(fileName: String): Free[Action, Reader] = liftF(GetReader(fileName))

  def close(reader: Reader): Free[Action, Unit] = liftF(CloseReader(reader))
}

object C {

  import Free.liftF

  case class ReadCSV(reader: Reader) extends Action[CSVParser] {
    override def run(): CSVParser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(reader)
  }

  def readCSV(reader: Reader): Free[Action, CSVParser] = liftF(ReadCSV(reader))
}

object I {

  import Free.liftF

  case class ProcessCSV(parser: CSVParser) extends Action[Unit] {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      for (r <- parser.asScala)
        println(r)
    }
  }

  def processCSV(parser: CSVParser): Free[Action, Unit] = liftF(ProcessCSV(parser))

}

object Runner {

  import cats.arrow.FunctionK
  import cats.{Id, ~>}

  val runner = new (Action ~> Id) {
    def apply[A](fa: Action[A]): Id[A] = fa.run()
  }

  def run[A](free: Free[Action, A]): A = {
    free.foldMap(runner)
  }
}


def test() = {
  val free = for {
    //        reader <- F.getReader("my_file.csv")
    reader <- F.getReader("AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv")
    csvRecords <- C.readCSV(reader)
    _ <- I.processCSV(csvRecords)
    _ <- F.close(reader)
  } yield ()

  Runner.run(free)
}
```

it seems to work OK in line-by-line mode.

Comment: Nice implementation!

Answer (score -1):

Here how I use the CSV file to read and do some operation on that - 
I use `scala.io.Source.fromFile()`

I create one `case class` of the type of `header` of CSV file to make the data more accessible and operational.

PS: I don't have knowledge of monads, as well as I am in beginner in Scala. I posted this as it may be helpful.

```
case class AirportData(id:Int, ident:String, name:String, typeAirport:String, latitude_deg:Double,
longitude_deg:Double, elevation_ft:Double, continent:String, iso_country:String, iso_region:String,
municipality:String)

object AirportData extends App {

def toDoubleOrNeg(s: String): Double = {
  try {
    s.toDouble
   } catch {
    case _: NumberFormatException => -1 
   }
 }

val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("resources/airportData/airports.csv")
val lines = source.getLines().drop(1)
val data = lines.flatMap { line =>
val p = line.split(",")
  Seq(AirportData(p(0).toInt, p(1).toString, p(2).toString, p(3).toString, toDoubleOrNeg(p(4)), toDoubleOrNeg(p(5)), 
      toDoubleOrNeg(p(6)), p(7).toString, p(8).toString, p(9).toString, p(10).toString))
 }.toArray   
 source.close()
 println(data.length)
 data.take(10) foreach println
}
```